# Forecast initialization with the fable package

Tags: r, forecast, fable

Suppose I estimate using the fable package the following model using daily data that cover 2019, where x is an exogenous explanatory variable. The terms `pdq(p = 1, d = 0, q = 0)` and `PDQ(P = 0, D = 0, Q = 0)` mean that this is an auto-regressive model.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)

load(file, "Some data.RData")

fit <- dta_2019 %>%
  tsibble() %>%
  model(ar = ARIMA(y ~ x + pdq(p = 1, d = 0, q = 0) + PDQ(P = 0, D = 0, Q = 0)))
```

Now I need to use that model to run a forecast on daily data for the year 2020 but suppose that the data begin in February 2020.

```
forecast_2020 <- fit %>%
  forecast(new_data = tsibble(dta_2020))
```

My understanding is that the value of the lag of y for the forecast, which is required given that this is an auto-regressive model, will be the last value observed in the estimation dataset (*dta_2019*). Can I initialize the value of y to something else? I have tried including a row in *dta_2020* that contains, in this particular example, the observation for January 31st, but that causes the forecast to begin on January 31st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ARIMA model (using `fable::ARIMA()`) you will also need to forecast January 2020 to obtain the February 2020 forecasts of interest. If the exogenous regressor is available for both months, then the forecasts can be computed. Providing future values of your exogenous regressor `x` is required, but future values of `y` are not needed for forecasting.

Answer (score 1):

Little update, in case it's still relevant.

I have found that using the function `fabletools::refit()` with `reestimate = FALSE` allows to update the model to the last relevant values supplied through `new_data` while preserving the estimates derived with the original dataset.

Thus you could provide a value from which to start for Jan 2020.

```r
require(fpp3)

dsub <- us_change[1:190, ]
m <- model(dsub, ARIMA(Consumption))

report(m)
#> Series: Consumption 
#> Model: ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,1)[4] w/ mean 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>           ar1     ma1     ma2     ma3     sar1    sma1  constant
#>       -0.3474  0.5684  0.3274  0.4123  -0.1367  0.3775    1.1352
#> s.e.   0.1579  0.1486  0.0938  0.0798   0.2164  0.1833    0.1313
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 0.3412:  log likelihood=-164.12
#> AIC=344.25   AICc=345.04   BIC=370.22
  
forecast(m)
  
#> # A fable: 8 x 4 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>   .model             Quarter   Consumption .mean
#>   <chr>                <qtr>        <dist> <dbl>
#> 1 ARIMA(Consumption) 2017 Q3 N(0.66, 0.34) 0.657
#> 2 ARIMA(Consumption) 2017 Q4  N(0.7, 0.36) 0.698
#> 3 ARIMA(Consumption) 2018 Q1 N(0.69, 0.38) 0.689
#> 4 ARIMA(Consumption) 2018 Q2 N(0.71, 0.42) 0.709
#> 5 ARIMA(Consumption) 2018 Q3 N(0.72, 0.42) 0.724
#> 6 ARIMA(Consumption) 2018 Q4 N(0.73, 0.42) 0.727
#> 7 ARIMA(Consumption) 2019 Q1 N(0.74, 0.42) 0.741
#> 8 ARIMA(Consumption) 2019 Q2 N(0.75, 0.43) 0.748

mfull <- refit(m, new_data = us_change, reestimate = FALSE)

report(mfull)

#> Series: Consumption 
#> Model: ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,1)[4] w/ mean 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>           ar1     ma1     ma2     ma3     sar1    sma1  constant
#>       -0.3474  0.5684  0.3274  0.4123  -0.1367  0.3775    1.1352
#> s.e.   0.1579  0.1486  0.0938  0.0798   0.2164  0.1833    0.1313
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 0.3207:  log likelihood=-168.58
#> AIC=339.17   AICc=339.19   BIC=342.46

forecast(mfull)

#> # A fable: 8 x 4 [1Q]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>   .model             Quarter   Consumption .mean
#>   <chr>                <qtr>        <dist> <dbl>
#> 1 ARIMA(Consumption) 2019 Q3 N(0.68, 0.32) 0.676
#> 2 ARIMA(Consumption) 2019 Q4 N(0.64, 0.34) 0.638
#> 3 ARIMA(Consumption) 2020 Q1 N(0.87, 0.36) 0.869
#> 4 ARIMA(Consumption) 2020 Q2 N(0.73, 0.39) 0.729
#> 5 ARIMA(Consumption) 2020 Q3  N(0.74, 0.4) 0.737
#> 6 ARIMA(Consumption) 2020 Q4  N(0.76, 0.4) 0.755
#> 7 ARIMA(Consumption) 2021 Q1  N(0.81, 0.4) 0.807
#> 8 ARIMA(Consumption) 2021 Q2  N(0.71, 0.4) 0.714
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That's a fantastic feature. Thanks for the update.